# Right order to do a merge with three branches in GIT

Tags: git, merge

Hy,

I have three branches in GIT(master, manteinance and evolve). The manteinance is for fixing errors and evolve is for adding new features. If I am developing a feature in the evolve branch, the right order to do a merge would be?:

1. From evolve to master
2. From master to manteinance

If I had some fixes in the manteinance branch the right order would be?

1. From manteinance to master
2. From master to evolve

Thanks

Comment: master is the branch that you will be using for deploying. 1. If you are developing a new feature in evolve merge it with maintenance and then merge to master. 2. If you are fixing errors merge maintenance with evolve and then with master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to merge branches that needs to have a full history in common.
So a new feature in `evolve` can indeed be merged to `master` when ready.

But the merge from `master` to `maintenance` is a special one: it is about `maintenance` to be reset to `master` in order to reflect the new `master`, and record fixes from that point in time:

```
git checkout master
git merge --ours maintenance
git checkout maintenance
git merge master
```

And a fix in `maintenance` doesn't mean merging to `master`, since `master` might have received evolution which renders that fix not pertinent.
A **[cherry-pick](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1994491/6309)** from certain fixes from the `maintenance` branch to `master` (if needed) or to `evolution` is more appropriate.

Comment: Ok, but lets imagine(I think most of the cases) the client has a preproduction and a production environment so we finish the new features and we merge into master for deploying. The client installs it in its preproduction environment to check these features and at the same time discovers a bug in its production environment. We dont have a branch then which reflects the production environment because of the merging into master so shouldnt we merge into master untill the clients installs the applicacion with the new features in production environment?

Comment: True, master should reflect prod only, not preprod. If you need a staging environment, you will need an additional branch to represent it.

Comment: Ok, so I would use the evol branch for deploying and when the client installs it in its production environment I will do the merge into master. If the client discovers a bug in the meantime in its production environment, I could use the master to create new branch for resolving the fix. What do you think about it?

Comment: Yes, making a fix branch from a master production state is a common practice.